# Looping though URLs with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I have created a page to read telemetry data from E.A. flood monitoring stations. It works, but the station results are sorted in random order and it's important they sort in the same order as the upstream level array. What am I missing?

```js
function getLevels() {
  var upstreamLevels = new Array("L1206", "L1203", "L1202", "L1108", "L1103", "L1308");
  var measuresTable = "";
  var label = "";

  for (x = 0; x < upstreamLevels.length; x++) {

    $.getJSON("https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/" + upstreamLevels[x] + "-level-stage-i-15_min-m/readings?_view=full&_sorted&_limit=3", function(json) {

      label = json["items"][0]["measure"]["station"]["label"];
      measuresTable = measuresTable + '<p>Station Name ' + label + '</div>';
      $("#measures").html(measuresTable);
    });
  }
}
window.onload = getLevels();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="measures"></div>
```

Comment: $.getJSON is async. You would need to manage this a different way.

Comment: What is the expected output, can you show?

Answer (score 2):

### Welcome to the Async world of programming.

> `$.getJSON function` is an async function, it will call your callback
>   when it gets data from the server and network request can complete in
>   any order, means the first request can be complete after the last one.

So to get data in dom in same order as `upstreamLevels`, you can either wait for request to complete and arrange accordingly ( like I did using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) ) 
or write custom logic to update dom from array index, for example, push result to new array, at same index as `upstreamLevels`, and update dom via loop through results array.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="measures">loading...</div>       
<script>
function getLevels() {
var upstreamLevels = new Array("L1206", "L1203", "L1202", "L1108", "L1103", "L1308");
var measuresTable = ""; 
var label ="";
function httpGet(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return $.getJSON(url, resolve)
   });
}
var promises = upstreamLevels.map(function(u) {
  return httpGet("https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/"+u+"-level-stage-i-15_min-m/readings?_view=full&_sorted&_limit=3")
})
Promise.all(promises)
.then(function(promiseResp) {
promiseResp.forEach( function(json) {
    label = json["items"][0]["measure"]["station"]["label"];
  measuresTable = measuresTable + '<p>Station Name ' + label + '</div>';
  $("#measures").html(measuresTable); 
})

})
}

window.onload = getLevels();
 </script>
```

you can use [fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) instead of $.getJSON, its use promise.
and you can use backtick to build string.

for example

```
`https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/measures/"${upstreamLevel}+"-level-stage-i-15_min-m/readings?_view=full&_sorted&_limit=3`
```

and 
     `measuresTable = ${measuresTable<p>Station Name ${label}</div>`

Comment: Wow thanks for the prompt response. Being a lightweight coder I would never have worked that out - respect.

Comment: if you found it correct and useful, you can select it as right answer

Comment: I did but "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."